# Unable to add object inside a array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I have this model. And I want to update the rating filed.

```
{ 
   "_id":"5d9f771a005ad60cfb76bc87",
  ...
   "riders":[ 
      { 
         "_id":"5d9ce9fd270eae22adb95d70",
         "profileimage":"",
         "rating":4 <------- Need to update this.
      }
   ]
}
```

If I do this

```
update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"riders.$.rating": rating}}
```

I'm getting this error

```
multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.}]}, {<nil>}]
```

If I do this it works fine.

```
update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"riders.0.rating": rating}}
```

But currently it has only one element so I can put `0` and it works but How to do this without `index`?

Comment: If there are multiple items in the array, which one are you going to update?

Comment: Which has the matching `_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positional operator `$` can be used to select the first matching array element in the query. Your query must include the array element:

```
query:=bson.M{"_id": <the document id>, "riders._id": <id you are searching for}
update:=bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"riders.$.rating": rating}}
```

Comment: Where to pass the query in `Collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)`

Comment: It should be the `filter`